# Modular GUI development as solution to IDE lag?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a GUI application in Visual Studio with WPF. It seems that I've added too many things to my window and VS lags horrifically. It's also a bit difficult to work with too many elements on the screen.

A lot of my functionality is grouped together in their own tabs or panels. Isn't there a way to just work on one panel at a time, and then tell VS to include that in so and so part of the main window?

Comment: Could you share a screen shot or code or some thing? to give us a better idea.
Usually, as long as an element is not display, it would not affect the performance, so having many tabs is ok. It could be many elements inside a tab or something..

Comment: Have you tried profiling?  Where are the bottle necks?

Comment: @SteveMitcham How would I profile Visual Studio itself?

Comment: 1 - stop using the Visual Studio designer. 2 - You're looking for `UserControl`s.

Comment: Oh, I misread your statement.  I thought you were talking about your app.

Comment: @bit Not sure if I have made this clear, but, it's not the program that lags. It's Visual Studio when I am in the Designer tab for my complicated window, with XAML displayed at the bottom. I'll add a screenshot when I have the chance.

Comment: @HighCore What else am I supposed to use? Could you please submit you comment as an answer (and elaborate on `UserControl`s)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076484/wpf-tutorial-for-creating-a-custom-usercontrol

Comment: @Superbest the XAML editor, just like everyone else. The designer is just to have a quick preview of your UI without hitting F5 (until there's enough XAML in your brain that you don't even need the editor and you can "see" the UI by looking at the XAML itself).

Comment: @HighCore Nah, I like clicking at things with my mouse ;)

Comment: @Superbest good luck trying to get a resolution independent auto adjustable UI from the designer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Break your functionality into UserControls, each with a specific purpose.  Then group them together into more complex combinations of controls and then utlimately your application window.

I would investigate a UI pattern like Model-View-ViewModel or MVVM which fits nicely with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

```
// MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Frame Name="EmbeddedView" Source="EmbeddedView.xaml"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

// EmbeddedView.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="EmbeddedView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    Embedded Text
</UserControl>
```

Actually, more than just `UserControl`s, you need the concept of Views and ViewModels - see Josh Smith's seminal article in MSDN Magazine:

[**WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Eventually, you'll want to move on to something like the following, but understand Views and ViewModels first:

[**Caliburn.Micro: Screens, Conductors, and Composition**](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition)